# Simulate mouse clicks in kernel space

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, mouse

I am trying to simulate keyboard and mouse clicks in kernel space, so they won't be able to be blocked in other applications (in contrast to user space simulation).

To achieve that goal, i found [this](https://github.com/jasonpang/Interceptor) library that is a C# wrapper for [this](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception)
project.
As I understood, it installs a driver to communicate hardware devices such as mouse and keyboard.
However, in contrast to the keyboard simulation that works flawlessly, i can't manage to make mouse simulation work:

No right or left clicks, only mouse moving is working.

This is the driver wrapper code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Interceptor
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate int Predicate(int device);

    [Flags]
    public enum KeyState : ushort
    {
        Down = 0x00,
        Up = 0x01,
        E0 = 0x02,
        E1 = 0x04,
        TermsrvSetLED = 0x08,
        TermsrvShadow = 0x10,
        TermsrvVKPacket = 0x20
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum KeyboardFilterMode : ushort
    {
        None = 0x0000,
        All = 0xFFFF,
        KeyDown = KeyState.Up,
        KeyUp = KeyState.Up << 1,
        KeyE0 = KeyState.E0 << 1,
        KeyE1 = KeyState.E1 << 1,
        KeyTermsrvSetLED = KeyState.TermsrvSetLED << 1,
        KeyTermsrvShadow = KeyState.TermsrvShadow << 1,
        KeyTermsrvVKPacket = KeyState.TermsrvVKPacket << 1
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MouseState : ushort
    {
        LeftDown = 0x01,
        LeftUp = 0x02,
        RightDown = 0x04,
        RightUp = 0x08,
        MiddleDown = 0x10,
        MiddleUp = 0x20,
        LeftExtraDown = 0x40,
        LeftExtraUp = 0x80,
        RightExtraDown = 0x100,
        RightExtraUp = 0x200,
        ScrollVertical = 0x400,
        ScrollUp = 0x400,
        ScrollDown = 0x400,
        ScrollHorizontal = 0x800,
        ScrollLeft = 0x800,
        ScrollRight = 0x800,
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MouseFilterMode : ushort
    {
        None = 0x0000,
        All = 0xFFFF,
        LeftDown = 0x01,
        LeftUp = 0x02,
        RightDown = 0x04,
        RightUp = 0x08,
        MiddleDown = 0x10,
        MiddleUp = 0x20,
        LeftExtraDown = 0x40,
        LeftExtraUp = 0x80,
        RightExtraDown = 0x100,
        RightExtraUp = 0x200,
        MouseWheelVertical = 0x400,
        MouseWheelHorizontal = 0x800,
        MouseMove = 0x1000,
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum MouseFlags : ushort
    {
        MoveRelative = 0x000,
        MoveAbsolute = 0x001,
        VirtualDesktop = 0x002,
        AttributesChanged = 0x004,
        MoveWithoutCoalescing = 0x008,
        TerminalServicesSourceShadow = 0x100
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MouseStroke
    {
        public MouseState State;
        public MouseFlags Flags;
        public Int16 Rolling;
        public Int32 X;
        public Int32 Y;
        public UInt16 Information;
    }  

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KeyStroke
    {
        public Keys Code;
        public KeyState State;
        public UInt32 Information;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Stroke
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public MouseStroke Mouse;

        [FieldOffset(0)] public KeyStroke Key;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The .NET wrapper class around the C++ library interception.dll.
    /// </summary>
    public static class InterceptionDriver
    {
        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_create_context", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateContext();

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_destroy_context", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void DestroyContext(IntPtr context);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_get_precedence", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void GetPrecedence(IntPtr context, Int32 device);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_set_precedence", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void SetPrecedence(IntPtr context, Int32 device, Int32 Precedence);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_get_filter", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void GetFilter(IntPtr context, Int32 device);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_set_filter", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void SetFilter(IntPtr context, Predicate predicate, Int32 keyboardFilterMode);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_wait", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 Wait(IntPtr context);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_wait_with_timeout", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 WaitWithTimeout(IntPtr context, UInt64 milliseconds);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_send", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 Send(IntPtr context, Int32 device, ref Stroke stroke, UInt32 numStrokes);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_receive", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 Receive(IntPtr context, Int32 device, ref Stroke stroke, UInt32 numStrokes);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_get_hardware_id", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 GetHardwareId(IntPtr context, Int32 device, String hardwareIdentifier, UInt32 sizeOfString);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_is_invalid", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 IsInvalid(Int32 device);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_is_keyboard", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 IsKeyboard(Int32 device);

        [DllImport("interception.dll", EntryPoint = "interception_is_mouse", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern Int32 IsMouse(Int32 device);
    }
}
```

This is the input Class API for the simulation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Interceptor
{
    public class Input
    {
        private IntPtr context;
        private Thread callbackThread;

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the driver traps no keyboard events, all events, or a range of events in-between (down only, up only...etc). Set this before loading otherwise the driver will not filter any events and no keypresses can be sent.
        /// </summary>
        public KeyboardFilterMode KeyboardFilterMode { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the driver traps no events, all events, or a range of events in-between. Set this before loading otherwise the driver will not filter any events and no mouse clicks can be sent.
        /// </summary>
        public MouseFilterMode MouseFilterMode { get; set; }

        public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the delay in milliseconds after each key stroke down and up. Pressing a key requires both a key stroke down and up. A delay of 0 (inadvisable) may result in no keys being apparently pressed. A delay of 20 - 40 milliseconds makes the key presses visible.
        /// </summary>
        public int KeyPressDelay { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the delay in milliseconds after each mouse event down and up. 'Clicking' the cursor (whether left or right) requires both a mouse event down and up. A delay of 0 (inadvisable) may result in no apparent click. A delay of 20 - 40 milliseconds makes the clicks apparent.
        /// </summary>
        public int ClickDelay { get; set; }

        public int ScrollDelay { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> OnKeyPressed;
        public event EventHandler<MousePressedEventArgs> OnMousePressed;

        private int deviceId; /* Very important; which device the driver sends events to */

        public Input()
        {
            context = IntPtr.Zero;

            KeyboardFilterMode = KeyboardFilterMode.None;
            MouseFilterMode = MouseFilterMode.None;

            KeyPressDelay = 1;
            ClickDelay = 1;
            ScrollDelay = 15;
        }

        /*
         * Attempts to load the driver. You may get an error if the C++ library 'interception.dll' is not in the same folder as the executable and other DLLs. MouseFilterMode and KeyboardFilterMode must be set before Load() is called. Calling Load() twice has no effect if already loaded.
         */
        public bool Load()
        {
            if (IsLoaded) return false;

            context = InterceptionDriver.CreateContext();

            if (context != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                callbackThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DriverCallback));
                callbackThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
                callbackThread.IsBackground = true;
                callbackThread.Start();

                IsLoaded = true;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsLoaded = false;

                return false;
            }
        }

        /*
         * Safely unloads the driver. Calling Unload() twice has no effect.
         */
        public void Unload()
        {
            if (!IsLoaded) return;

            if (context != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                callbackThread.Abort();
                InterceptionDriver.DestroyContext(context);
                IsLoaded = false;
            }
        }

        private void DriverCallback()
        {
            InterceptionDriver.SetFilter(context, InterceptionDriver.IsKeyboard, (Int32) KeyboardFilterMode);
            InterceptionDriver.SetFilter(context, InterceptionDriver.IsMouse, (Int32) MouseFilterMode);

            Stroke stroke = new Stroke();

            while (InterceptionDriver.Receive(context, deviceId = InterceptionDriver.Wait(context), ref stroke, 1) > 0)
            {
                if (InterceptionDriver.IsMouse(deviceId) > 0)
                {
                    if (OnMousePressed != null)
                    {
                        var args = new MousePressedEventArgs() { X = stroke.Mouse.X, Y = stroke.Mouse.Y, State = stroke.Mouse.State, Rolling = stroke.Mouse.Rolling };
                        OnMousePressed(this, args);

                        if (args.Handled)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        stroke.Mouse.X = args.X;
                        stroke.Mouse.Y = args.Y;
                        stroke.Mouse.State = args.State;
                        stroke.Mouse.Rolling = args.Rolling;
                    }
                }

                if (InterceptionDriver.IsKeyboard(deviceId) > 0)
                {
                    if (OnKeyPressed != null)
                    {
                        var args = new KeyPressedEventArgs() { Key = stroke.Key.Code, State = stroke.Key.State};
                        OnKeyPressed(this, args);

                        if (args.Handled)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        stroke.Key.Code = args.Key;
                        stroke.Key.State = args.State;
                    }
                }

                InterceptionDriver.Send(context, deviceId, ref stroke, 1);
            }

            Unload();
            throw new Exception("Interception.Receive() failed for an unknown reason. The driver has been unloaded.");
        }

        public void SendKey(Keys key, KeyState state)
        {
            Stroke stroke = new Stroke();
            KeyStroke keyStroke = new KeyStroke();

            keyStroke.Code = key;
            keyStroke.State = state;

            stroke.Key = keyStroke;

            InterceptionDriver.Send(context, deviceId, ref stroke, 1);

            if (KeyPressDelay > 0)
                Thread.Sleep(KeyPressDelay);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Warning: Do not use this overload of SendKey() for non-letter, non-number, or non-ENTER keys. It may require a special KeyState of not KeyState.Down or KeyState.Up, but instead KeyState.E0 and KeyState.E1.
        /// </summary>
        public void SendKey(Keys key)
        {
            SendKey(key, KeyState.Down);

            if (KeyPressDelay > 0)
                Thread.Sleep(KeyPressDelay);

            SendKey(key, KeyState.Up);
        }

        public void SendKeys(params Keys[] keys)
        {
            foreach (Keys key in keys)
            {
                SendKey(key);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Warning: Only use this overload for sending letters, numbers, and symbols (those to the right of the letters on a U.S. keyboard and those obtained by pressing shift-#). Do not send special keys like Tab or Control or Enter.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        public void SendText(string text)
        {
            foreach (char letter in text)
            {
                var tuple = CharacterToKeysEnum(letter);

                if (tuple.Item2 == true) // We need to press shift to get the next character
                    SendKey(Keys.LeftShift, KeyState.Down);

                SendKey(tuple.Item1);

                if (tuple.Item2 == true)
                    SendKey(Keys.LeftShift, KeyState.Up);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a character to a Keys enum and a 'do we need to press shift'.
        /// </summary>
        private Tuple<Keys, bool> CharacterToKeysEnum(char c)
        {
            switch (Char.ToLower(c))
            {
                case 'a':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.A, false);
                case 'b':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.B, false);
                case 'c':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.C, false);
                case 'd':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.D, false);
                case 'e':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.E, false);
                case 'f':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.F, false);
                case 'g':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.G, false);
                case 'h':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.H, false);
                case 'i':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.I, false);
                case 'j':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.J, false);
                case 'k':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.K, false);
                case 'l':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.L, false);
                case 'm':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.M, false);
                case 'n':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.N, false);
                case 'o':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.O, false);
                case 'p':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.P, false);
                case 'q':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Q, false);
                case 'r':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.R, false);
                case 's':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.S, false);
                case 't':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.T, false);
                case 'u':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.U, false);
                case 'v':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.V, false);
                case 'w':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.W, false);
                case 'x':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.X, false);
                case 'y':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Y, false);
                case 'z':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Z, false);
                case '1':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.One, false);
                case '2':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Two, false);
                case '3':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Three, false);
                case '4':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Four, false);
                case '5':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Five, false);
                case '6':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Six, false);
                case '7':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Seven, false);
                case '8':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Eight, false);
                case '9':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Nine, false);
                case '0':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Zero, false);
                case '-':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.DashUnderscore, false);
                case '+':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.PlusEquals, false);
                case '[':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.OpenBracketBrace, false);
                case ']':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.CloseBracketBrace, false);
                case ';':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.SemicolonColon, false);
                case '\'':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.SingleDoubleQuote, false);
                case ',':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.CommaLeftArrow, false);
                case '.':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.PeriodRightArrow, false);
                case '/':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.ForwardSlashQuestionMark, false);
                case '{':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.OpenBracketBrace, true);
                case '}':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.CloseBracketBrace, true);
                case ':':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.SemicolonColon, true);
                case '\"':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.SingleDoubleQuote, true);
                case '<':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.CommaLeftArrow, true);
                case '>':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.PeriodRightArrow, true);
                case '?':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.ForwardSlashQuestionMark, true);
                case '\\':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.BackslashPipe, false);
                case '|':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.BackslashPipe, true);
                case '`':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Tilde, false);
                case '~':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Tilde, true);
                case '!':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.One, true);
                case '@':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Two, true);
                case '#':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Three, true);
                case '$':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Four, true);
                case '%':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Five, true);
                case '^':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Six, true);
                case '&':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Seven, true);
                case '*':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Eight, true);
                case '(':
                    return new Tuple<Keys,bool>(Keys.Nine, true);
                case ')':
                    return new Tuple<Keys, bool>(Keys.Zero, true);
                case ' ':
                    return new Tuple<Keys, bool>(Keys.Space, true);
                default:
                    return new Tuple<Keys, bool>(Keys.ForwardSlashQuestionMark, true);
            }
        }

        public void SendMouseEvent(MouseState state)
        {
            Stroke stroke = new Stroke();
            MouseStroke mouseStroke = new MouseStroke();

            mouseStroke.State = state;

            if (state == MouseState.ScrollUp)
            {
                mouseStroke.Rolling = 120;
            }
            else if (state == MouseState.ScrollDown)
            {
                mouseStroke.Rolling = -120;
            }

            stroke.Mouse = mouseStroke;
            InterceptionDriver.Send(context, 12, ref stroke, 1);
        }

        public void SendLeftClick()
        {
            SendMouseEvent(MouseState.LeftDown);
            Thread.Sleep(ClickDelay);
            SendMouseEvent(MouseState.LeftUp);
        }

        public void SendRightClick()
        {
            SendMouseEvent(MouseState.RightDown);
            Thread.Sleep(ClickDelay);
            SendMouseEvent(MouseState.RightUp);
        }

        public void ScrollMouse(ScrollDirection direction)
        {
            switch (direction)
            { 
                case ScrollDirection.Down:
                    SendMouseEvent(MouseState.ScrollDown);
                    break;
                case ScrollDirection.Up:
                    SendMouseEvent(MouseState.ScrollUp);
                    break;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Warning: This function, if using the driver, does not function reliably and often moves the mouse in unpredictable vectors. An alternate version uses the standard Win32 API to get the current cursor's position, calculates the desired destination's offset, and uses the Win32 API to set the cursor to the new position.
        /// </summary>
        public void MoveMouseBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, bool useDriver = false)
        {
            if (useDriver)
            {
                Stroke stroke = new Stroke();
                MouseStroke mouseStroke = new MouseStroke();

                mouseStroke.X = deltaX;
                mouseStroke.Y = deltaY;

                stroke.Mouse = mouseStroke;
                stroke.Mouse.Flags = MouseFlags.MoveRelative;

                InterceptionDriver.Send(context, 12, ref stroke, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                var currentPos = Cursor.Position;
                Cursor.Position = new Point(currentPos.X + deltaX, currentPos.Y - deltaY); // Coordinate system for y: 0 begins at top, and bottom of screen has the largest number
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Warning: This function, if using the driver, does not function reliably and often moves the mouse in unpredictable vectors. An alternate version uses the standard Win32 API to set the cursor's position and does not use the driver.
        /// </summary>
        public void MoveMouseTo(int x, int y, bool useDriver = false)
        {
            if (useDriver)
            {
                Stroke stroke = new Stroke();
                MouseStroke mouseStroke = new MouseStroke();

                mouseStroke.X = x;
                mouseStroke.Y = y;

                stroke.Mouse = mouseStroke;
                stroke.Mouse.Flags = MouseFlags.MoveAbsolute;
            InterceptionDriver.Send(context, 12, ref stroke, 1);
        }
        {
            Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Anyone have idea why mouse clicks doesn't work but mouse moving does (via driver too)?
I am using Windows 10.

Thanks alot!

Edit: The purpose of this software is accessibility program for handicap people that can't use mouse clicks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you should be ashamed with your accusations. You deserve to be handicap to understand others special needs.

Comment: We get endless questions here from people trying to defeat online poker apps. It does get a little wearing. What applications are you trying to defeat?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am learning Security as an hobby, and I use IDA Pro as a tool, but it blocks the regular 'Send Input' method, so I had to try the driver space simulation way.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone not being able to send mouse clicks,
try going into the Inteceptor.SendMouseEvent method

and in the line

```
InterceptionDriver.Send(context, 12, ref stroke, 1);
```

change the 12 to 11, so now the line looks like this

```
    InterceptionDriver.Send(context, 11, ref stroke, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - at the library i used, the mouse device id was hard coded to 12, which was totally wrong.

Now it is wroking like a charm :)

Comment: Have you changed the hardcoded value to device id value received on driver callback to make it work?